# How can I add or rename files in Visual Studio while the project is running?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

How can I add or rename files in Visual Studio while the project is running?
I am currently developing a ASP.NET 5 web application and I continuously need new TypeScript files or html files. It is a pain to always have to stop and start the project again.

I have a gulp watcher running that copies all html changes and compiles all TypeScript files into one app.js towards wwwroot.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. All that intelli-sense and call stack/debug instrumentation gets built up based on a known source compilation. If you changed the source it would invalidate your debugging experience as it is not dynamic.

Comment: VS2013 allows you to add add html and TypeScript files while debugging, but you can't rename them once added which seems silly as they're non-compiled.

Comment: Maybe you can start your project without debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you just need run through a few steps first.

1. Run your local site but bypass debug mode (CTRL + F5). Debug mode requires recompilation to pickup file modifications since the debugger isn't attached to the process.
2. Install dnx-watch by running this command `dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher`. This will add file change monitoring to your project. This is new as of beta8, you can read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx).